# C# - generating points along a fraction of a circles circumference

Tags: c#, algorithm, collision-detection, geometry

I have the below algorithm which generates a number of points along the circumference of a circle for collision events in my program. (This works perfectly as far as I can tell).

```
        bool Collision_True = false;
        for (int Angle = 0; Angle <= 359; Angle += 5)
        {
            int X = (CentreX + (Radius * Math.Cos(Angle));
            int Y = (CentreY + (Radius * Math.Sin(Angle));
            Point point = new Point(X, Y);

            if (Collision_True == false)
            {
                Collision_True = Player_Collisions(point); 
            }
        }
        return Collision_True;
```

However I want to change this so it only generates points on the bottom third of the circle, I tried changing the values in the for loop as follows:

```
        for (int Angle = 120; Angle <= 240; Angle += 5)
        {
            ...
        }
```

But the points generated are still around the complete circumference of the circle instead of just the bottom third.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the output from your trig functions for various inputs of relevance?

Comment: Angle should be radians. You’ll need to convert from degrees.

Comment: when you do find your answer, this code can run slightly more effeciently if you put the Collision_True = Player_Collisions(point); above the if block, then make the if block check for true, then put a return Collision_True; statement inside the block

Comment: Fixed it, thanks (just needed to convert it to degrees and make the angle variable a double)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to radians

```
for (int angleDegrees = 120; angleDegrees <= 240; angleDegrees += 5)
{
    double angleRadians = angleDegrees / 180 * Math.PI;
    int X = (CentreX + (Radius * Math.Cos(angleRadians));
    int Y = (CentreY + (Radius * Math.Sin(angleRadians));

...
```